# use different css classes for different custom option values

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

When i inspect **Custom option values** which are displaying in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) , i got below code is reason to display those values.

code :

```
<span id="options-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
```

inspect element :

[image]

here, is there any chance we can display different color for different custom option values, for example, **Black = > Black, Green = > Green** .

can we use different `css classes or ids` for each value ?

```
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>

    <div class="input-box">
        <?php echo $this->getValuesHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()): ?>
            <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX): ?>
                <span id="options-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif;?>      
    </div>

</dd>
```

Comment: You can use swatches for that and also you can write your own css(.options_453_3{}, .options_453_2{}) for the ids and use it.Only you can add the option_id as your class.

Comment: @mujas i am using `simple product with custom options` , i am not using `configurable product`, can you please tell what is the css class for code i posted in question , is it `_455_2` ?

Comment: If these options are same for every products.You can write css class like options_453_3{}, .options_453_2{} and apply these classes to your label dynamically.

Comment: yes, we have same values :`Black & Green` for all products, i tried adding internal css as `.options_453_3
 {
  color : red; 
  
 }

 
 .options_453_2
 {
  color : red; 
  
 }` , but it did't displayed in "red" color..... is the way i am doing is right ?

Comment: <span class="label" style="
    background-color: black;
"><label for="options_453_2">Black </label></span> you can use like this.instead of writing black you can use the label value.better you can use different classes.

Comment: @mujas when i added your code, it displaying value `Black` again and for that it applying different css , but i wanted to add css for exisiting `custom cases` which are displaying with help of php code..... please check image : http://prntscr.com/dxkq74  ,  you can check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html)

Comment: @mujas Thanks a lot for your support......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not straight way to do it you can do it by javascript

This solution for dropdown

```
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect"); //select id here

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tex=x.options[i].text;  // option text 
        var tex = tex.toLowerCase(); //make it lower
        x.options[i].style.backgroundColor = tex; // set the background color for that

    }
```

you can use css

```
  label[for=options_455_2]
   {
      /* ...add css here... */
   }
```

Comment: i tried like this , seems i am doing something wrong, please check this : `var x = document.getElementById("options_455_2"); //select id here

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tex=Black.options[i].text;  // option text 
        var tex = tex.toLowerCase(); //make it lower
        x.options[i].style.backgroundColor = red; // set the background color for that

    }`

Comment: if you check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) & update the answer as per my requirement, that will be really helpfull..... , "custom option value" = `black`.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento added the simple solution for you

Comment: yes, now i can apply different css for different custom values,  give me 10 min, i have one more doubt.....